Program: human-like species, they are terrified of some sort of monster, that is themselves in next stage of their lifecycle
This was a programme (similar to The Outer Limits, but earlier). There is a human-like species that peacefully live in a community. There is some type of monster that lives outside the village and there is a constant battle as the monsters are always trying to get close to the 'villagers', who chase them away. In the end, the monsters are found out to be the next life stage of the villagers, and some have retained memories of their families before they changed which is why they want to see them again.

Was it a cartoon?

No, not a cartoon. It was like an Outer Limits, or Twilight Zone thing i think.

Reminds me of something either from ST:TNG or ST:V tbh

Do you remember approximately when / what year you saw this? That could help narrow it down.

That's a cool plot!

So, if this was TV prior to The Twilight Zone or The Outer Limits, was it in black and white? Or was it perhaps a movie in color?

As far as i remember it was in colour.

I'm trying to remember roughly how long ago it was, it was filmed in colour but it was at least 20 years ago +

I looked at the blurbs for The Ray Bradbury Theater and for Masters of Science Fiction and didn't find it. Could this be in a horror anthology series? (would still qualify as a question)

@Ali Christie You say what you are asking about was probably a tv program "like The Outer Limits but earlier".  That could be misleading since There were two The Outer Limits programs, one in 1963-1965 and the other in 1995-2002.  Could you specify which The Outer Limits program you think your program was earlier than.

Did this smbc strip from within the last week make you think of it? https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/frank

@blobbymcblobby The Original Series episode "Miri" has a similar plot but most of the "monsters" are dead when the episode starts.

@PastychomperthanksMonica i remember Miri, great TOS episode!

Could this be the Doctor Who story The Mutants, a third Doctor story from 1972? There are enough similarities that I'm throwing it out as an answer.

he [The Doctor] deduces the Mutant phase is a natural part of the Solonian life-cycle.


Hi, i've just had a look at the write-up and it isnt the one i'm thinking of, but it is similar. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Could this be the Stargate Atlantis episode Epiphany?
A village exists within a time a dilation field. They are meditating and trying to become ascended beings. They are persistently attacked by a gigantic monster comprised of their own fears and anxieties.
At the end, having managed to conquer these fears, they are able to ascend to a higher state of being.




Sounds interesting, but its not the same one i'm afraid. Thanks for the suggestion though!

It is possibly the Dr. Who serial "Full Circle" in 4 episodes from 25 October 1980 to 15 November 1980.  I note that one of the human looking natives, Adric, stows away on the Tardis at the end and becomes a companion of the doctor for a while.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_Circle_(Doctor_Who)
Yuu say what you are asking about was probably a tv program "like The Outer Limits but earlier".  That could be misleading since There were two The Outer Limits programs, one in 1963-1965 and the other in 1995-2002.

There are 2 episodes of Buck Rogers in the 25th Century that have a similar theme. In season 2 episode 8 The Crystals, there is a monster who is after a young girl with amnesia, and by the end of the episode they find out that these are the same species and she will turn into a creature like him. The next episode in the series is the Satyr and it is a similar theme in that the men in the area were turned into satyr-like creatures, and one is trying to reunite with his family. I've seen both of these several times, and I think either would fit the description. The first is definitely an evolutionary thing, the second I believe had to do with something they ate or drank and it only affected the men.

Sounds a bit like the relationship between the Eloi and the Morlocks and their respective relationship to humans from H. G. Wells' The Time Machine. A film rendition was released in 1960, which seems about the right time frame.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Machine_(1960_film)

If memory serves, the Morlocks and Eloi were both descendants of 20th century humans, but went down different evolutionary paths due to living in different environments. So the Morlocks were not the next stage in the Eloi's lifecycle, but rather a sister race.

@LogicDictates You would be correct. However, I think the answer is still a worthwhile response since some users do occasionally misremember details (I have definitely been among them before, haha).

@LogicDictates, I completely agree. It doesn't match all the criteria. We should also mention that there is no real parallel to the 'memories of their families before they changed', meaning it's a transformation of individuals rather than a product of evolution. But there still seemed to be enough parallels to warrant the suggestion. The monster/villager duality is quite like predator/prey and while neither are the next stage in a human's lifecycle, they're both descendants as you rightly point out.

Thanks for the suggestion, but it definitely isn't the Time Machine. It does share a number of similarities though so good thought.
